# How do I properly return a List into a Xamarin ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, xamarin, mvvm

I'm trying to return a list into Xamarin using an ASP.NET Web API, and working with Xamarin Forms with the Prism MvvM Framework.

I have an API the returns a list in the JSON format, below is the example. This returns data correctly through Postman (I believe):

```
        public async Task<List<OpenWorkOrder>> GetOpenWorkOrders()
    {
        using (WO db = new WO())
        {

           List<OpenWorkOrder> woLog = await db.OpenWorkOrders
                .OrderBy(x => x.WOID)
                .ToListAsync();
                    
                return woLog;   

        }
    }
```

Here is an example of the data returned in postman:

```
[
    {
        "WOID": "M0000001",
        "AssetNumber": "Item 2",
        "WorkRequested": null,
        "Active": true,
        "ID": 1
    },
    {
        "WOID": "M0000002",
        "AssetNumber": "Item 1",
        "WorkRequested": null,
        "Active": true,
        "ID": 2
    }
]
```

I'm struggling to bind this to a ListView in Xamarin Forms.
I want to use a button to navigate to a page, and on that page load the list view, for the user to select the Work Order they are performing.

Here is the View and Binding:

```
    <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Test"></Label>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OpenOrders}"></ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the ViewModel, where I call for the data:

```
    private object _openWO;

    public object OpenOrders
    {
        get { return _openWO; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _openWO, value); }
    }
    private async Task<OpenWorkOrder> OpenWO()
    {
        
        var client = new RestClient("http://apiurl/Maint/api/");
        var request = new RestRequest("GetOpenWorkOrders", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse<OpenWorkOrder> response2 = await client.ExecuteAsync<OpenWorkOrder>(request);
        var OpenOrders = response2.Data;
        return OpenOrders;
    }


    public async void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        try { await OpenWO();
            Console.WriteLine("Await Called!"); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await _dialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Exception Handled", ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    }
```

The screen opens fine when I navigate to it, the I see it runs Write Line, I'm just not sure why I'm not seeing any data on the form.

Where am I messing up?

EDIT:
After Speaking with Jason, here is some of the updated code.

```
private List<OpenWorkOrder> _openWO;

public List<OpenWorkOrder> OpenOrders
{
    get { return _openWO; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _openWO, value); }
}
```

In regards to the updated code:

```
   private async Task<OpenWorkOrder> OpenWO()
    {
        
        var client = new RestClient("apiurl/api/");
        var request = new RestRequest("GetOpenWorkOrders", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse<OpenWorkOrder> response2 = await client.ExecuteAsync<OpenWorkOrder>(request);

        if (response2.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RESPONSE DATA!!!!" +response2.Content+"RESPONSE DATA!!!!");

            var OpenOrders = response2.Data;
            return OpenOrders;

        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Response status code:      " + response2.StatusCode.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is the OpenWorkOrder class:

```
    public class OpenWorkOrder
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string WOID { get; set; }
    public string AssetNumber { get; set; }
    public string WorkRequested { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why is `OpenOrders` an `object` and not a `List<OpenWorkOrder>`?  A `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` must be an `IEnumerable`

Comment: I'm still learning!
I updated the OpenOrders and changed those to a List. 

I can see the data being written in the console, writing the response2.Content, but settings OpenOrders to the response2.Data still seems like the list view is blank.

Comment: is OpenWorkOrder a single order or a collection?  It sounds like your service returns multiple orders, but you are deserializing into a single order object

Comment: It is a collection of orders.

Comment: can you please post the code for that class, and update your other code to reflect the changes you made?

Comment: I am editing the original post for the updated code!

Comment: there are multiple issues here.  First, the method `OpenWO` returns ONE `OpenWorkOrder` object, not a list of them.  Second, when you call it with `await OpenWO()` that just calls the method and throws away the result instead of assigning it.  You are using the same name `OpenOrders` for a class property and a local method variable and acting like they are the same thing when the are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to modify your REST request to deal with a `List<OpenWorkOrder>`

```
// this will return a List, not a single object
private async Task<List<OpenWorkOrder>> OpenWO()
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://apiurl/Maint/api/");
    var request = new RestRequest("GetOpenWorkOrders", Method.GET);
    // get a list here too
    IRestResponse<List<OpenWorkOrder>> response2 = await client.ExecuteAsync<OpenWorkOrder>(request);

    // return a list
    return response2.data;
}
```

then when calling the method you need to assign the results to your property

```
OpenOrders = await OpenWO();
Console.WriteLine("Await Called!"); }
```

Comment: Thank you! I Am getting much closer. 

It looks to be pulling entries now, but I'm not sure about bindind the values I return.
So it seems to pull the entries, but in Xamarin the values are blank. If that makes sense.

Can I mark this as the Answer and PM you?

Comment: you haven't created a template for your ListView.  You have to define what you want each row to look like and which values to bind

Comment: Hey Jason, I marked yours as the answer! I was in process of creating the ListView and binding the data for each row. That works, however it almost seems like it doesn't refresh the UI initially.

With the application running in debug, the ListView populates but doesn't display that binding, until I remove and re-add the binding. Then at that point the data display. If that makes sense.